# Update ClassNames on State change React js

Tags: css, reactjs, classname

Is there a way to update a classNames var (in this case 'btClasses') on State change?

```
...
    state = {
       active: true
    };

    btClasses = classNames({
      'main-class': true,
      'activeClass': this.state.active
    });

    _handleBtn = () => {
       this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
    } 

    return (
        <button 
           onClick={this._handleBtn} 
           className={btClasses} \>
    );
...
```

Comment: To what you want to update it? And yes you can

Comment: When I press the button state.active is being updated but 'activeClass' is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you initialize the `className` once, usually, you pass it as property:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: true
  };

  handleBtn = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.handleBtn}
        className={classNames({
          "main-class": true,
          activeClass: this.state.active
        })}
      >
        {this.state.active ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit eager-stonebraker-yy9l4]

Answer (score 0):

The `btClasses` in your current implementation does not get updated after the first render. To compute its value with the current state, you can turn `btClasses` into a function:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: true,
  };

  btClasses = () =>
    classNames({
      'main-class': true,
      activeClass: this.state.active,
    });

  _handleBtn = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this._handleBtn} className={this.btClasses()} />;
  }
}
```

or simply inline it:

```
render() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={this._handleBtn}
      className={classNames({
        'main-class': true,
        activeClass: this.state.active,
      })}
    />
  );
}
```